# pymongo $exists :false vs False

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I am reading data from pymongo and need to check if column exists or not

```
[doc for doc in col.find{"IAM":{"$exists":false}}
```

I am getting and error near false

- Tried so far:

I have tried to convert false to False, but in mongodb it is not returning anything. how to check if column exists in pymongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to correct:

- @R2D2 is correct; the syntax should be `find({})`.
- The predicate should be `False` (capitalised) in python *
- You can replace [for doc in doc ...] with just list()

So your final statement is:

```
result = list(col.find({"IAM": {"$exists": False}}))
```

*In the mongo shell / javascript it is `false` (lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like syntax error , the object you are searching with find need to be enclosed with this type of brackets "find()" instead of this ones "find{}" - curly